# "fail to excute createRadialGradient,the provided double value is non-finite" on my canvas animation

Tags: animation, canvas, colors

I was intending to make a color gradient circle animation with canvas but I got this error ***"fail to execute createRadialGradient, the provided double value is non-finite"*** in the console. I am coding this with my MAC but when I copied those code to my windows PC it is just run perfectly. which is really confused me. the following error code would be like:

```
 //...within my circle constructor
  this.color = function(){
                    var grad = ctx.createRadialGradient(this.x,this.y,0,this.x,this.y,this.r);
                    var colorArray = ['green','red','yellow','blue','purple'];
grad.addColorStop(0,colorArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*colorArray.length)]);
grad.addColorStop(.2,colorArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*colorArray.length)]);
return grad
```

I just don't think there is any error with my color()function but when I called this with animation in later phase the error just popped out. Is there anyone could help me with this? All the source code could be viewed at https://github.com/mystreie1126/CanvasExperiment/blob/master/Color%20gradient%20Circle%20Animation/colorCircle.html

thanks in advance

Comment: The problem is in your for loop, before you call `new Circle` you are using `x = someval - r` before you initialize `r`. so for the first Circle, `x` and `y` will be `NaN`. Declare `r` first, and also, do not declare `var variable = XXX` in a for loop, either declare `var variable;` before the loop, or declare it with the ES6 `let`.